# i2cdetect shows every possible address

Tags: i2c, ds1307

I was trying to turn on I2C following this tutorial http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/11/enabling-the-i2c-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/

But I have problem which I cannot solve.
The command `i2cdetect -y 1` returns

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a UU 1c 1d 1e 1f
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f
30: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

I don't know why it shows all addresses and how can I fix this.
I didn't connect anything to my Raspberry Pi. I've just put SD card and installed default OS using NOOBS. But when problem appeared I connected my RTC DS1307 but it didn't affect on i2cdetect output.

Comment: Pin 3 was the answer for me. I had an LED on pin 3 and when I moved it, the interface cleared up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally this happens because something is pulling SDA (pin 3) low.

The i2cdetect program checks for the existence of a device by sending its address then letting SDA float high.  If the device exists it should pull SDA low to signal its presence.

Check your wiring to make sure SDA hasn't been inadvertently connected to ground.

Comment: I've used multimeter putting first test lead on SDA and second test lead on GND. I've found there is connection between them. Is it wrong?

Comment: Check the voltage between pin 3 and pin 6 (ground).  It should read 3V3.  If it does not there is seomthing wrong.  Do you have anything connected to the expansion header like a ribbon cable?

Comment: It's 0.06V between pin 3 and 6. I have nothing connected to my device.

Comment: I'd examine the PCB tracks to see if there is a solder bridge.  Do you have a gpio library installed?  Pin 3 would read low if it was actively being driven low, but by default it should be floating high.

Comment: PCB looks fine. I have fresh Raspbian with updates. I thought gpio library is required only if I want to write code in Python. Should I install python-rpi.gpio? Or maybe there is other gpio library?

Comment: I was just thinking of the quickest way of checking the mode and level of SDA.  RPi.GPIO comes pre-installed with Raspbian.  I'm not sure how to use RPi.GPIO to test the mode and level in an non-intrusive way.  wiringPi has the gpio readall command which would display the information.  My pigpio library has a gpio status Python script. http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html

Comment: Mode is ALT0 and level is 1.

Comment: @wja They are as expected.  I'd expect to see 3V3 between pin 3 (high) and pin 6 (ground) rather than the measured 0.06V.  Carefully try the volatge between pin 1 (3V3) and pin 6.  Perhaps your meter is faulty.  http://pi.gadgetoid.com/pinout

Comment: There is 3,3V between pin 1 and 6. It's weird because now I checked 3 and 6 again - it's 3,3V as expected. But still ic2detect -y 1 returns all adresses. I have two different multimeters and both of them give the same result.

Comment: @wja Oh dear.  The gpios seem to be working as expected.  The I2C bus should operate when SDA/SCL are in mode ALT0, and both should normally read as high if the bus is not in use.  I'm not aware of another scenario which would give the results you are seeing.

Comment: Should I assume that my RaspberryPI is broken?

Comment: I'm not sure, try wiringPi's pin test and pigpio's [gpio test](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Shell_code) with NOTHING connected to the expansion header.

Comment: Nothing connected, PIN 3 - mode ALT0, level 1 (wiringPi and pigpio give the same result).

Comment: The tests I mentioned test each of the user gpios for read and write access, not just SDA.

Comment: I checked again with nothing connected
http://pastebin.com/RbQGDSGV

Comment: @wja You need to run the pin test and gpio test commands.

Comment: This is pintest with failures http://pastebin.com/Udsa1H0E
I don't know which test I should run, test.sh is trying to turn leds in endless loop (but I have nothing connected to my pins).

Comment: It does look like SDA is broken.  You could confirm with [gpio test](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/gpiotest.zip).

Comment: gpio test result http://pastebin.com/Vfsc301s

Comment: I'd say that is fairly conclusive.  Broadcom numbered gpios 2, 4, and 9 are broken.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because broken i2c device was connected (I accidentally reverse connected it to voltage/ground before)

Try using another i2c device

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with a restart. I'm not sure what was wrong but I suspect it had something to do with me using the SDA pin for a button before I tried setting up the i2c module. I'm adding this just in case someone else has made a similar mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this happen when I was using the wrong AC adapter; switching to an 'official' AC adapter cleared up the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my PI zero... Near SDA (pin 3) and the SD card slot there are two resistors, touched the connections with a soldering iron and it works now.